# Change Value of ParamInfo after adding to DynamicParameters?

Tags: dapper

I'm calling a stored proc in a `foreach` loop and would like to change the value of one of the parameters on each iteration. Currently, there doesn't seem to be any way to access the parameters once they've been added to DynamicParameters although from reading the source, I can see that DynamicParameters does keep an internal Dictionary. Any reason why this isn't public or if there's another way to get at the ParamInfos to change values?

**Update**

What I have currently:

```
foreach ( var fooID in fooIDs )
{
    var dynamicParameters = new DynamicParameters();
    dynamicParameters.Add( ParameterNames.BarID, barID );
    dynamicParameters.Add( ParameterNames.FooID, fooID);

    connection.Execute( ProcNames.MyProc, dynamicParameters, commandType:CommandType.StoredProcedure );
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501319/is-there-anyway-to-iterate-through-a-dapper-dynamicparameters-object ?

Comment: Sam, I updated my question with what I'm doing at the moment (which works). What I wanted to do was to declare and instantiate the DynamicParameters outside the loop and then update just one of the parameters before calling the stored procedure each time. Is that what the example in your link is doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Re-Add the parameter.

```
// Call Add() with new values.
dynamicParameters.Add(ParameterNames.BarID, differentBarID);
```

Comment: Cool. One thing to mention is that some DBs actually behave differently if the parameters are not passed in order. I'm dealing with IBM DB2, and the SQL parameter order actually matters. Will this Add function modify the parameter and add it to the end?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real reason [DynamicParameters](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/source/browse/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#1945) is so secret about what it does, the `ParamInfo` class could be exposed and I would be happy to provide proper iteration/modification properties and/or methods. If you feel like you would like to pitch in, please submit a patch.

In the mean time you can simply implement `IDynamicParameters` which is the trivial interface we use to dispatch this to the underlying command, in your app. You can use DynamicParameters as a starting point.

Comment: The link about dynamic parameters is dead.  It would have been better to have a code example as part of the answer.