# Is there anyway to iterate through a Dapper DynamicParameters object?

Tags: dapper

I need to make a generic logger to record certain insert/update statements so that my testers can verify the data being inserted is correct.

My first thought was that I would just use a function that accepted DynamicParameters and I would foreach through the DynamicParameters to generate a string to list the parameter's name and value and make them easier to read for the testers.

Unfortunately, Dapper.DynamicParameters does not contain a public definition for "GetEnumerator"

Here is basic example of what I was hoping to do:

```
string myFormattedListofParameters = "";
foreach (var p in myDynamicParameters)
{
myFormattedListofParameters += p.Name + "=" + p.Value.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var name in p.ParameterNames)
            {
                var pValue = p.Get<dynamic>(name);
                sb.AppendFormat("{0}={1}\n", name, pValue.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Sam. BTW, love Dapper, it has saved me so much time and headache. When I try the code above I get... 'Dapper.DynamicParameters' does not contain a definition for 'ParameterNames'.

Comment: @Sam Saffron I'm receiving the following exception when I follow your code: [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   Dapper.DynamicParameters.Get(String name) in c:\Dev\Dapper\Dapper\SqlMapper.cs:2574

Comment: I'm getting this same exception as Gary here.  Any updates on this?

Comment: Still having issues with this -- what version of Dapper does this require to work?

Comment: Still getting the SQLMapper.cs null reference in the latest NuGet when Get<T> is called on the DynamicParameters. Any news yet on when this will be resolved?

Comment: I believe the `Get<T>(string name)` function only works after `IDbDataParameter` instances are attached to the parameters. In other words, one cannot get a value until the parameters are used in Execute or Query or some other such function. If you call `Get<T>(string name)` before using the parameters, you get the null reference exception.

Answer (score 8):

```
    string ParametersToString(DynamicParameters parameters)
    {
        var result = new StringBuilder();

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            var firstParam = true;
            var parametersLookup = (SqlMapper.IParameterLookup)parameters;
            foreach (var paramName in parameters.ParameterNames)
            {
                if (!firstParam)
                {
                    result.Append(", ");
                }
                firstParam = false;

                result.Append('@');
                result.Append(paramName);
                result.Append(" = ");
                try
                {
                    var value = parametersLookup[paramName];// parameters.Get<dynamic>(paramName);
                    result.Append((value != null) ? value.ToString() : "{null}");
                }
                catch
                {
                    result.Append("unknown");
                }
            }

        }
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: The cast to SqlMapper.IParameterLookup helped me avoid the NullReferenceException I was getting when trying to iterate through the collection prior to being used on an IDbConnection instance. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this, helped when writing unit tests that asserted the correct parameters where being wired to the correct values in calls to our Dapper wrapper

Answer (score 1):

One line with Linq:

```
string.Join(", ", from pn in sprocParams.ParameterNames select string.Format("@{0}={1}", pn, (sprocParams as SqlMapper.IParameterLookup)[pn]))
```

I'm using that to log with log4net:

```
Log.InfoFormat("Exec {0} {1}", storedProc, string.Join(", ", from pn in sprocParams.ParameterNames select string.Format("@{0}={1}", pn, (sprocParams as SqlMapper.IParameterLookup)[pn])));
```

Answer (score -3):

Just in case,

```
var pmaster = new Dapper.DynamicParameters();                            
SortedList l = new SortedList();
l.Add("param1", object1);
l.Add("param2", object2);
l.Add("param3", object3);
l.Add("param4", object4);

foreach(var key in l.Keys)
{
  var val = l[key];
  pmaster.Add(key.ToString(), val);
}
```

Worked for me.

Comment: This wouldn't help in situations where I want to encapsulate the abstraction away. If I were to put this in a method say FormatDynamicParameters, I would now require that all of my consumers pass in an instance of DynamicParameters and an IList implementation.