# Can a Dapper DynamicParameters object be enumerated like a dictionary of parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, dapper

I know I can use a `ParameterDirection` with Dapper.DynamicParameters:

```
var parameters = new DynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("iparam", 42);
parameters.Add("oparam", null, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Output);
connection.Execute(sql, parameters);
```

But can I do so when using a `Dictionary<string, object>`?

```
var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
parameters.Add("iparam", 42);
parameters.Add("oparam", /* ??? */ );
connection.Execute(sql, parameters);
```

Alternatively, how may I iterate over a `DynamicParameters` in order to get the parameter names and values?

Original title:

> Can a Dapper parameter with ParameterDirection be added using a
>   dictionary?

Comment: Why do you want to use a `Dictionary`?

Comment: I can iterate over a dictionary. I can't iterate over whatever DynamicParameters is.

Comment: Then you would have to create your own data structure for holding `ParameterDirection` and `DbType` along with parameter value and store it in the dic. And then write code to convert it to `DynamicParameters `

Comment: @CharlesBurns You can iterate over it like this: `foreach (var paramName in parameters.ParameterNames) { var value = parameters[paramName]; }`

Comment: Alternatively, you can modify the Dapper source, have it implement `IEnumerable` and have it return the internal dictionary's `.GetEnumerator()`. Might be a useful patch for others, too. See: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/blob/855d3c1ad1e1ba2c1fd35bf08ac6445c53bea84d/Dapper%20NET40/SqlMapper.cs#L4576 - Or alternatively, you might be able to extend the class since it's a `partial` class.

Comment: True, but only after the statement has been executed. I need to iterate before. I've considered doing this, but I would have to couple my SQL  generation with the calling function, which I think is icky. :(

Comment: @CharlesBurns Why only after the statement has been executed? Whenever you add to the `DynamicParameters`, it's internally stored in a dictionary, which is where `ParameterNames` gets its values from - nothing to do with executing the query

Comment: Good question. When I try to iterate over the dictionary  before the statement has been executed, I get a null reference error. Otherwise I'd concert everything to DynamicParameters since they are more flexible in other ways.

Comment: @CharlesBurns That must have been from something else. The code definitely doesn't *appear* to have anything that would throw a null reference exception from my above snippet (the iteration). The internal `parameters` is never null, and the indexer explicitly checks for nulls

Comment: @Rob: I would think the same, but it really doesn't work. This is lightly explained in this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501319/is-there-anyway-to-iterate-through-a-dapper-dynamicparameters-object
Unfortunately, Sam Saffron didn't respond (though I thank him for all his responses and his design work on Dapper).

Comment: @CharlesBurns Hi Charles, I've just setup a test locally - and I can't reproduce your null reference error. What version of Dapper are you using? See here for the code I tried: http://pastebin.com/4ZASXWx7 . Are you able to grab the source of `Dapper` and try again? If you're still getting the null reference, please let me know what line it occurs on (the line number quoted in the linked question is from an out-dated version of Dapper)

Comment: @CharlesBurns Actually - it turns out this was recently fixed (May 11 by Marc Gravell) - Commit here: https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/24e55162f47780f509ee373c081234431bc5d576 . If you update your version of Dapper [to a 1.42 or later, I believe], you should be able to iterate the parameters :)

Comment: ` var otherValue = parameters.Get<dynamic>(paramName);` still immediately throws `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` but the array-based notation... works! Wow, you went above and beyond for this question. Please post your code as an answer  and I'll mark it correct and ++.

Comment: @CharlesBurns I've posted a more detailed explanation. Happy to help out, as I use `Dapper` extensively myself, and if the bug still existed, I was looking to fix it myself so I don't run into the same issue myself :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in Dapper. This is confirmed to work in the latest NuGet package:

```
foreach (var paramName in parameters.ParameterNames)
{
    var value = ((SqlMapper.IParameterLookup)parameters)[paramName];
}
```

However, it's a bit verbose. Locally using the [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) source (not a NuGet package), I was able to run this code without error (As of writing that's commit [b77e53](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/b77e5384bb0e85496fd38a2e5cc7c2d545ef3c52)):

```
foreach (var paramName in parameters.ParameterNames)
{
    var value = parameters.Get<dynamic>(paramName);
}
```

According to [Charles Burns' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751477/can-a-dapper-dynamicparameters-object-be-enumerated-like-a-dictionary-of-paramet#comment53385198_32751477), it still throws an exception, which leads me to believe the patch hasn't made it into NuGet yet. The commit which fixes `Get<dynamic>` is [here](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net/commit/24e55162f47780f509ee373c081234431bc5d576)

Comment: Just before I read your last comment, I was a sitting down to implement parallel dictionary/DynamicParameters to use the former for retrieval, the latter for execution. I would have had to shower at least six times after.

Answer (score 8):

The `DynamicParameters` object can contain several sections for each time it has been appended. So it's not enugh to iterate through `ParameterNames` (it will be empty) like in the answer above.

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> ToParametersDictionary(this DynamicParameters dynamicParams)
{
    var argsDictionary = new Dictionary<String, Object>();
    var iLookup = (SqlMapper.IParameterLookup) dynamicParams;
    //if (dynamicParams.ParameterNames.Any())
    //{
        // read the parameters added via dynamicParams.Add("NAME", value)
        foreach (var paramName in dynamicParams.ParameterNames)
        {
            var value = iLookup[paramName];
            argsDictionary.Add(paramName, value);
        }
    //}
    //else
    //{
        // read the "templates" field containing dynamic parameters section added
        // via dynamicParams.Add(new {PARAM_1 = value1, PARAM_2 = value2});
        var templates = dynamicParams.GetType().GetField("templates", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        if (templates != null)
        {
            var list = templates.GetValue(dynamicParams) as List<Object>;
            if (list != null)
            {
                // add properties of each dynamic parameters section
                foreach (var objProps in list.Select(obj => obj.GetPropertyValuePairs().ToList()))
                {
                    objProps.ForEach(p => argsDictionary.Add(p.Key, p.Value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return argsDictionary;
}
```

and `GetPropertyValuePairs(..)` is

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> GetPropertyValuePairs(this object obj, String[] hidden = null)
{
    var type = obj.GetType();
    var pairs = hidden == null
        ? type.GetProperties()
            .DistinctBy(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name)
            .ToDictionary(
                propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name,
                propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null))
        : type.GetProperties()
            .Where(it => !hidden.Contains(it.Name))
            .DistinctBy(propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name)
            .ToDictionary(
                propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name,
                propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(obj, null));
    return pairs;
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    var seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    return source.Where(element => seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)));
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realize that parameters could be hidden due to compartmentalization. This hasn't happened to me yet -- Rob's first `foreach` works for me since the Dapper patch, but that may be because I build a single `DynamicParameters` object per transaction and use it only once.

Comment: Yes Charles, `foreach` works fine if you append the `DyanmicParameters` with single parameters: `dynParams.Add("PARAM_1", aValue); ...` but does not work if you append it with objects containing the parameters: `dynParams.AddDynamicParams(new {PARAM_1 = aValue1, PARAM_2 = aValue2});` so maybe i should even remove `if (dynamicParams.ParameterNames.Any())` from `ToParametersDictionary(..)` method and check the templaces in all cases.