# Can a get DbType from Dapper DynamicParameters?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, dapper

I need iterate through Dapper `DynamicParameters`. So, I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751477/can-a-dapper-dynamicparameters-object-be-enumerated-like-a-dictionary-of-paramet) answer to get value of parameter.

```
foreach (var paramName in parameters.ParameterNames)
{
    var value = ((SqlMapper.IParameterLookup)parameters)[paramName];
}
```

Now, I need parameter DbType. Is it possible to get this information?

Comment: Please try to be specific, instead of just providing a hyperlink.  What have you tried?  What error do you receive ?

Comment: I have `DynamicParameters` instance. So, I iterate it (just like in example) and just don't know how to get DbType property of `DynamicParameter` instance.

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if Dapper provides a better solution for this or not, but thanks to reflection, there is nothing impossible!

```
var t = parameters.GetType().GetField("parameters", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);

if (t != null) 
{  
     foreach (DictionaryEntry dictionaryEntry in (IDictionary)t.GetValue(parameters))
     {
        var dbType = (DbType)dictionaryEntry.Value?.GetType().GetProperty("DbType")?.GetValue(dictionaryEntry.Value);  
     }
}
```

Comment: Weirdly, parameters created using the DynamicParameters(object) constructor don't show up here.  

`var p = new DynamicParameters( new { Bacon = 123 });
p.Add("Pastrami", 456);`

In your code above, in t.GetValue(p),  Bacon is missing but Pastrami is included... I can't see why.   (And no.  Dapper doesn't provide a better solution.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this! Please check the code below:

```
 private List<DbType> GetParameterType<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var properties = type.GetProperties().Select(property => property.PropertyType.Name).ToList();

        var dbTypes = new List<DbType>();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            var tryParse = Enum.TryParse<DbType>(prop, out var result);
            if (tryParse)
                dbTypes.Add(result);
        }

        return dbTypes;
    }
```

And then, the call of this is simple: `var dbTypes = GetParameterType<T>();` where `T` is your object